# Can't get to facebook admin page for

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, admin

I had a like button on the main page of my site without the og tags and now I have added the og tags and I'm trying to access the admin page but it does not show up next to the button. the og type is blog.

I've used the debug tool and everything appears like expected and it shows my fb account as the admin.  but the admin page link does not show up with the button.  I have liked the page but instead of showing the admin link it's just disabled.

from my fb if I go to http://www.facebook.com/insights/ the page shows up and I can see stats for it.  but what I want is to be able to send a message to people who have liked the page.

I've searched all over the place and found other people with this problem but nowhere where anyone has resolved it.  If I can't get the admin page link showing up next to the like button is there an alternative way to get to the admin page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue and I've found this related bug in facebook developers website :
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/160664854023586?browse=search_4e946433c82379f78564182